# building method for LINQ query to strip chars from records

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to strip the following chars from my records using LINQ to SQL query

`"\";:'.,=+!@#$%^&*(_)~{}[]\\|<>? aeiouAEIOU"`

I can do it with my linq query here

```
from p in customers 
select new {customer_name = String.Concat(p.First_name.Replace("A","@"),p.Last_name.Replace("A","@")), address =  p.Address.Replace("A","@") }
```

but I know there must be a better way to do this!  I tried a method in c# to strip the chars but since this is linq to sql it doesn't work. The error says "that has no supported translation to SQL"

I need some ideas and code samples on how to write this routine in c#.  Or possibly write a sql function to do this and example of how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

However you choose to update the records, you can use the `Regex.Replace()` method to replace unwanted characters in a string.

For example:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// ...

string unwanted = @"["";:'.,=+!@#$%^&*(_)~{}\[\]\\|<>? aeiouAEIOU]";

string subject = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

string result = Regex.Replace(subject, unwanted, string.Empty);
// Thqckbrwnfxjmpdvrthlzydg
```

[Read more about Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and the [.NET implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: linq error says "no supported translation to SQL" - any other ideas?

Comment: Get the customer objects, update them, and THEN save the updated values back to the database, instead of trying to update them as part of the select?